# JPQL / HQL fetch join syntax for compatibility with EclipseLink & Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, eclipselink, jpql, fetch

I would like to be able to swap my JPA implementation between EclipseLink & Hibernate with a simple property change. I can do this ok but what is causing me problems is the named query validation. Using EclipseLink I have to write fetch joins like so:

```
SELECT id 
FROM IndexDefinition id 
JOIN FETCH id.index 
JOIN id.index i
JOIN FETCH i.indexVersions
```

But when validating this query using Hibernate I get the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list
```

So I can change the query to be HQL friendly like so:

```
SELECT id 
FROM IndexDefinition id 
JOIN FETCH id.index i
JOIN FETCH i.indexVersions
```

But this then causes the following exception in EclipseLink:

```
Exception Description Syntax error parsing the query [IndexDefinition.getForIndex] SELECT id FROM IndexDefinition id JOIN FETCH id.index i, syntax error at [id].
Internal Exception MismatchedTokenException(78!=-1)
```

I know I can use query hints at my DAO level to perform a fetch join but is there a way of pleasing both JPA implementations with a specific fetch join syntax?

Comment: What versions of Hibernate and EclipseLink are you using exactly? The first query runs fine with Hibernate EM 3.4.0.GA for me.

Comment: Sorry, was missing a line from the query. I have corrected with an edit. I am using version 3.5.1-Final of hibernate-entitymanager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems that [nested joins](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Nested_Joins) are not supported by the JPA 1.0. From the JPA 1.0 specification:

> #### 4.4.5.3 Fetch Joins
>
> A FETCH JOIN enables the fetching of
>   an association as a side effect of the
>   execution of a query. A FETCH JOIN is
>   specified over an entity and its
>   related entities.
>
> The syntax for a fetch join is
>
> ```
> fetch_join ::= [ LEFT [OUTER] | INNER ] JOIN FETCH join_association_path_expression
> ```
>
> The association referenced by the
>   right side of the FETCH JOIN clause
>   must be an association that belongs to
>   an entity that is returned as a result
>   of the query. **It is not permitted to
>   specify an identification variable for
>   the entities referenced by the right
>   side of the FETCH JOIN clause, and
>   hence references to the implicitly
>   fetched entities cannot appear
>   elsewhere in the query**.
>
> The following query returns a set of
>   departments. As a side effect, the
>   associated employees for those
>   departments are also retrieved, even
>   though they are not part of the
>   explicit query result. The persistent
>   fields or properties of the employees
>   that are eagerly fetched are fully
>   initialized. The initialization of the
>   relationship properties of the
>   employees that are retrieved is
>   determined by the metadata for the
>   Employee entity class.
>
> ```
> SELECT d
> FROM Department d LEFT JOIN FETCH d.employees
> WHERE d.deptno = 1
> ```
>
> A fetch join has the same join
>   semantics as the corresponding inner
>   or outer join, except that the related
>   objects specified on the right-hand
>   side of the join operation are not
>   returned in the query result or
>   otherwise referenced in the query.
>   Hence, for example, if department 1
>   has five employees, the above query
>   returns five references to the
>   department 1 entity.

So, while nested joins might be supported by some JPA providers, the behavior is not standardized.

#### References

- JPA 1.0 Specification

  - Section 4.4.5.3 "Fetch Joins"
- JPA Wikibook

  - [Nested Joins](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Nested_Joins)